Show that $ \int_{\cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k} |f(x)|dx\le 2a|\cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k| $
Let $f\in L_1([a,b])$ be Lebesgue integrable. Let $I_k$ be a sequence of subintervals of $[a,b]$. If there is $a>0$ so that $$\int_{I_k}|f(x)|dx\le a|I_k|$$
where $|I_k|$ is the Lebesgue measure of $I_k$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that
$$
\int_{\cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k} |f(x)|dx\le 2a|\cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k|
$$

We know that

for every $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ so that whenever $m(E)<\delta$,  $$\int_E |f(x)|dm(x)<\epsilon$$

Take $I_1,\dots, I_{n_0}$ so that $$m(\cup_{k=1}^{n_0} I_k)\ge m(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k)-\delta,$$
and there is no point of $[a,b]$ belongs to three of $I_k$ for $k=1,\dots, n_0$.
Then we have
$$
\int_{\cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k} |f(x)|dx=\int_{\cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k\setminus \cup_{k=1}^{n_0} I_k} |f(x)|dx+\int_{\cup_{k=1}^{n_0} I_k} |f(x)|dx\le \epsilon + \sum_{k=1}^{n_0}\int_{I_k}|f(x)|dx
$$
where we apply our Lemma.
I am confused about the following steps in proof:
Then
$$
\epsilon + \sum_{k=1}^{n_0}\int_{I_k}|f(x)|dx\le \epsilon + a\sum_{k=1}^{n_0}|I_k|\le \epsilon+2a m(\cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k)
$$
